# hyperledger how would a user join a business network through a iOS app?

Tags: ios, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am hoping to create an iOS app for my business network, but do not understand how a user would be able to join and use a network considering that they would not have a business network card beforehand? If a network card is necessary how would I create and upload one through an iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

a network is exposed to the outside world via an API. So you create and deploy your network, say you deploy to the IBM cloud, for example. You expose it via an API which can be deployed somewhere else. At this point your app / user can simply talk to the API itself without caring about the complexity behind it. I suggest you go over the documentation, it will explain how this works in detail

Comment: I understand that, however in order to interact with the API in multi-year mode you need a network card. I'm asking how one would create the network card through a iOS app. - Thanks

Comment: you can't create a card through your ios app, you need to run a set of composer commands to do that which means you must have the composer installed and running. You can't just create cards wherever you want